# class members that are inheritable

Tags: java

I was studying for my OCA cert. and stumbled on a sample question.

it gives you a code and asks you to figure out which option is correct. The code looks like:

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    string address;
    protected String phonenumber;
    public float experience;
}
class Programmer extends Employee {
    programmer (String val){
      name = val;
    }
    String getName() {
      return name;
    }
}
class Office{
    public static void main (String args[]){
      new Programmer ("Harry").getName();
    }
}
```

Now the answer for this question was "compilation error". I understand this is correct because you can't access the String 'name' since it is private.

But among the option there was one that said: "The derived class Programmer can't access variables of its base class in its constructors."

Now, I thought this was basically saying that constructor 'Programmer' can't access variable 'name' from its base class 'Employee' (because the variable is public). Which lead me to believe this was also a correct statement. However, the answer page from the book stated compilation error option was the only correct statement.

I was hoping if anyone could explain why that statement is wrong.

Comment: You wrote 'string' and 'programmer' in lower case. Is that by intention? I guess not; else the second woulnd't be a constructor. And you state '...because the variable (name) is public, which isn't, as you recognized earlier. Do you mean another one?

Comment: If the class can't compile, no other options matter; it isn't legal code so nothing can access anything.

Comment: Q: Do you think "Programmer" can access base class member "phonenumber"?  Or "address"?  SUGGESTION: modify your code so that it compiles (I see at least two errors), and try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The derived class Programmer can't access variables of its base class
>   in its constructors."

Well, a class can access variables, independent of it being in the constructor, in a method, or in the declaration part. That just doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the statement. I thought the option was stating that constructor couldn't access String variable name, but instead the option was saying that constructor couldn't access variables of its base class in general.